# Use of "sys.argv" on python program converted to an .exe

Tags: python, windows, registry

I have a .exe basically written in python added to the windows right click menu bar such that when files(single or multiple) are dropped, it opens up the terminal and does action..
But for me, each file seems to open a separate terminal.
I want it such that all files are in the same list.

Comment: I spawns a separate process for each file. (i think)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.